# Confirmation email showing server details instead of noreply email

Tags: php, email

I am using this script to send not only an email to domain of the registered person, but also a confirmation email to the person who sent the message to the registered person.
The php block is:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['tel']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['m'])){
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $s = $_POST['subject'];
    $t = $_POST['tel'];
    $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
    $to = "info@domain.com";
//    $from = $e;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email: '.$e.'</b><br>Subject: '.$s.'<p>'.$m.'</p>';
    $conf_sender = 'Name of company <no-reply@domain.com>';
    $conf_mess = "Dear ".$n."\nThank you for your enquiry. Your message has been sent and will be sent and will be dealt with shortly.\nPlease wait for a reply";
    $conf_mess .="\nYour Message: ".$m."\n";
    $conf_mess .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $conf_mess .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $headers = "From: $e\n";
    $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $s, $message, $headers) ){
        mail($e,$s,$conf_mess,$conf_sender);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

This is also appearing at the end of the email, which shouldn't be showing

> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: You should consider using PHPMailer or something similar. Getting the headers and encoding and every correct is a hell of a job. PHPMailer does this job for you.

Comment: But it was working until I added something to the script

Comment: What did you add? Still. debugging this is difficult without looking at the actual mail content (with headers). I just advice for your own sake to use PHPMailer for send emails.

Comment: I think it was the concatenation to the confirmation message

Comment: What "shouldn't be showing" is showing because you explicitly told it to, at the end of `$conf_mess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Send **2 mails** with **2 differents messages** the first mail got **$message** and the second **$conf_mess** so look what you put and is normal your are showing :

cos you concat to $conf_mess this :

**$conf_mess .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";**

```
if( mail($to, $s, $message, $headers) ){
    mail($e,$s,$conf_mess,$conf_sender);
```

You want this :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['tel']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['m'])){
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $s = $_POST['subject'];
    $t = $_POST['tel'];
    $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
    $to = "info@domain.com";
//    $from = $e;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email: '.$e.'</b><br>Subject: '.$s.'<p>'.$m.'</p>';

    $conf_sender = 'Name of company <no-reply@domain.com>';
    $conf_sender .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $conf_sender .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $conf_mess = "Dear ".$n."\nThank you for your enquiry. Your message has been sent and will be sent and will be dealt with shortly.\nPlease wait for a reply";
    $conf_mess .="\nYour Message: ".$m."\n";


    $headers = "From: $e\n";
    $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $s, $message, $headers) ){
        mail($e,$s,$conf_mess,$conf_sender);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The mail sent to the server looks fine, nothing wrong with it

Comment: @Mr. Bean I just tell you why you show at the end 
 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 i didn't tell you the mail isn't sending, just show you why you show at the end the text you talk about read plz.